# how to change size of navigation view menu items and text?? How to change space between menu?

Tags: java, android, space, navigationview

I am making a sliding menu. I have successfully created a navigation drawer and menu items inside the navigation view in groups. But I want to make the items closer to each other. Can I change the spacing or size of items and text?
Please help...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create following Theme in your styles.xml for Navigation Drawer and you're done.

```
<style name="NavigationTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">02dp</item>
</style>
```

Apply this theme to your navigation drawer layout

Comment: @Amrut can we reduce the distance between the icon and the text?

Answer (score 12):

You can apply following Theme in your styles.xml for Navigation Drawer

```
<style name="NavigationTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item  name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

Apply this theme in Navigation Drawer

```
android:theme="@style/NavigationTheme"
```

Comment: thank u for reply.. It works to change the text size. But how to make items closer to each other?? I want to change spacing between them.

Answer (score 2):

The others solutions didn't worked for me, so I finally solved using the following theme:

```
<style name="NavigationTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="listPreferredItemHeightSmall">40dp</item>
</style>
```

And I applied it to the NavigationView:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:theme="@style/NavigationTheme"
```

Answer (score 0):

add these line in navigation drawer layout of your xml file.

```
   <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView

    app:itemVerticalPadding="10sp"/>
```